# Is there any interests database for download?

Tags: database

I need a database of interests for a coming project.
By saying "interests" I mean like:
Sports - Football, Basketball and so on...

Is somebody know something like this?
I just don't want start writing thousands (or even millions) of interests.

Comment: A database structure is mostly determined by what you want to save in it. Although you are asking for a database that stores interests, it sounds like you may need more than just a list. What do you actually need?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there wasn't something like this, although I don't know offhand where to get it. Think of various ways to phrase your question, or alternate names for what you're looking for, and keep up the Google searches.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is probably an Ontology, which is mostly related to the fields of Knowledge Base management, Semantic Web, Knowledge Representation et al. There are ontologies described using the OWL language for pretty much everything, so you will probably find something useful if you start with these keywords.

Comment: This question is probably too vague, compared to say asking for a database of tables of countries, together with their 2 character abbreviations, say. You probably can scrape the information automatically, parse it, spit it out in proper SQL, run that against the database language of your choice (MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite...), and you've now got what you want. Maybe consulting Wikipedia is a good start for overview/general information of categories of everything.

Comment: Did you manage to get the data from anywhere?

Answer (score 4):

Try to google on "interests list" or "hobbies list" and the write simple parcer to extract all (based on neko-html for example). Examples of useful links:

http://www.notsoboringlife.com/list-of-hobbies/

http://www.buzzle.com/articles/list-types-of-hobbies/

Also it is possible to ask admins of any dating sites to make a simple DB-query to get relevant result.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API from google called Freebase. I allows you suggest to the user what input he should give the same way google search suggests you what to look for.

[Freebase](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/suggest)